# Streaming raw PCM over socket.io results in noise

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, socket.io, web-audio-api

I'm working off the fantastic sample [here](https://github.com/vin-ni/Google-Cloud-Speech-Node-Socket-Playground/tree/master/srcLogOnly).

In essence, I am capturing audio from the mic using getUserMedia and then downsampling each frame to an Int16Array of 16000 samples per second.

On the server side, I am able to receive the audio and using the [wav](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wav) package, I am able to save WAV files as well.

The problem is when I *don't* want to downsample (yes, I know the bandwidth implication but that's my requirement).

I'm able to stream raw audio (in `Float32Array`) and able to save it as a WAV. However, there's a lot of white noise added in.

When I downsample on the server side, the WAV package is unable to handle it because it is no longer a viable WAV frame.

I tried to wrap the mic samples using

```
var samples = new Float32Array(e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0))
socket.emit('binaryData',samples.buffer);
```

and received it on the server side with

```
socket.on('binaryData',function (data){
 var recovered = new Float32Array(data);
 wavFileWriter.write(recovered.buffer);
});
```

But that doesn't work either.

I'm now wondering if Socket.io does something to the data that trips the [downsample](https://github.com/vin-ni/Google-Cloud-Speech-Node-Socket-Playground/blob/51ddef23b3cf95c3f903c352cf2b62745ed8cf00/srcLogOnly/public/js/client.js#L285) function.

Or am I missing something obvious here?

Edit 1: in my quest to rule out Socket.io issues, I created the server with these settings without any improvement:

```
{
    perMessageDeflate: false,
    httpCompression: false,
    maxHttpBufferSize:1e8
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Solved it with:

```
const f32 = new Float32Array(data.buffer, 0, data.byteLength / Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT);
```